# Using public SSL for dynamic domains to map on single cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

I am creating a portal where I am letting my customers map their domains or sub-domains to my CloudFront distribution. So, this way customer comes in and enter a domain name "domainname.com" or "test.domainname.com", and this domain will hit to my CloudFront distribution.

I know that we cannot add multiple certificates in CloudFront, but let me explain my requirements.

We have a site builder. The site builder application is hosted on my server which is on my datacenter which is NOT on Amazon and no plans to move it on Amazon.

The customer comes in and enters a domain name example customer.com. We will generate the Public SSL certificate for this domain and then will add a new record on our hosted zone under route53 saying customer.mycompany.com. This is because we created a wildcard certificate for *.mycompany.com and mapped to the CloudFront.

Now we can able to browse the site with customer.mycompany.com successfully. Though if I am adding a CNAME for customer.com to route to customer.mycompany.com, it is not picking the certificate from amazon for customer.com and CloudFront is not accepting the request from customer.com.

Things which I already finished:

I am able to generate the SSL through web API. 
I also have done with setting up wildcard certificate for *.mycompany.com.
I also finished creating a subdomain record in route53 for customer.mycompany.com and point it to my CloudFront distribution.

Now I am stuck at if the user browses customer1.com or 2, 3, or any it should route to my CloudFront with picking the SSL certificate from Amazon.

It would be great for any help, please.

Comment: We have a site builder and faced the same issue. Remember CloudFront distributions are free. We solved the issue by creating a new CloudFront distribution per tenant with their custom domain and SSL certificate. Then give them the CloudFront url and tell them to alias the domain to the CloudFront url in their DNS. We manage the process with Lambda and AWS Step Functions. You’ll have to contact AWS support and explain your use case and get a limits increase for SSL certificates and CloudFront distributions.

Comment: oh, thanks, this opened one more way. But, will it not get so costly for going on creating CloudFront distribution for each domain and each certificate? I am using a basic package on Amazon. Can I still request them to increase the limit of certificates? Is there any limit for creating cloudfront distributions?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, have an app platform - would like to tell customers to map their subdomains by CNAME pointing to something (like CloudFront). I too ran into the SSL requirement. Once i hit 10 certs, any more i hit the limit. So either i request more ... or come up with an alternative.